# Show/Hide elements one by one repeatedly using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to show/hide a set of elements one by one repeatedly.

Following is the `HTML`:

```
<div id="1">Div 1</div>
<div id="2">Div 2</div>
<div id="5">Div 5</div>
```

I've tried the below script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var repeat = function () {
        $('#1').show();
        $('#1').delay(1000).hide();
        $('#2').hide();
        $('#2').delay(1000).show();
        $('#2').delay(3000).hide();
        $('#5').hide();
        $('#5').delay(3000).show();
        $('#5').delay(6000).hide();
    };
    setInterval(repeat, 6000);
});
```

But I get all the divs visible at once. After the first 10 seconds everything hides and the script is done. Any pointers here is greatly appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1u9zk37/)

Comment: Can you make this into a jsfiddle?

Comment: What are you actually tring to do..?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I am trying to make an Info screen that cyckles infomation in a contiunues loop without interaction.
I will see if I can fiddle it.

Comment: Looking at the code, looks like you want to show the div#1 for 1 sec and hide it and then show div#2 for 2 sec and hide it and show div#5 for 3 sec and repeat the process. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, You're looking for [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var repeat = function() {
    $('#1').fadeToggle(1000);
    $('#2').fadeToggle(1000);
    $('#5').fadeToggle(1000);
  };
  setInterval(repeat, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">Div 1</div>
<div id="2">Div 2</div>
<div id="5">Div 5</div>
```

---

If you want to display the elements one by one, You can use the complete callback of `fadeToggle()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var repeat = function() {
    $('#1').fadeToggle(1000, function() {
      $('#2').fadeToggle(1000, function() {
        $('#5').fadeToggle(1000);
      });
    });

  };
  setInterval(repeat, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">Div 1</div>
<div id="2">Div 2</div>
<div id="5">Div 5</div>
```

Comment: I think the elements are supposed to show in sequence, not all at once.

Comment: @isherwood Maybe... I updated the answer in case.. not scalable though :)

Comment: Thank you @t-j this the second code snippet was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

initially you are not setting the display propety to none. you should do that first so that it doesnt show up at once eg:

```
<div id="1" style="display:none;">Div 1</div>
```